# ¿Cómo utilizar el mismo HTML para mostrar los resultados de una búsqueda usando un formulario con el método GET en Django?

Tags: python, django, formularios, get

A través de un formulario `<Form>` (que contiene un `input` de tipo `text` y un `button` tipo `submit`) usando el método `GET`, estoy buscando el texto ingresado en una tabla de mi base de datos y lo renderizo en otro html (`resultados2.html`), hasta todo bien. Ahora quiero mostrar lo buscado en el mismo html (`solucion.html`) de mi formulario, por lo tanto, lo que hago es dejar vacío el atributo `action=""`, pero no funciona. Al dejar vacío el atributo `action=""` me doy cuenta que no está ingresando a la función `DocsBuscar2` del archivo `views.py`, por tal motivo no se está ejecutando la búsqueda y pues no muestra ningún resultado.

Archivo `views.py`:

```
.
.
.

def DocsBuscar2(request):
    print("Prueba de ingreso")
    if request.GET['buscando']:
        palabraBuscada = request.GET['buscando']
        DocBusc = Documento.objects.filter(Q(titulo__icontains = palabraBuscada) | Q(contenido__icontains = palabraBuscada) | Q(contenido__icontains = palabraBuscada)).distinct()
        print(DocBusc)
        return render(request, "resultados2.html",{'DocBusc':DocBusc, "query":palabraBuscada})

    else:
        palabraBuscada="No has introducido nada"
        return render(request, "resultados2.html",{"query":palabraBuscada})
.
.
.
```

Archivo `solucion.html`:

```
<!--Formulario-->
      <form action="" method="GET">
        <h1>Busqueda de Documentos</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="buscando..." name="buscando">
        <button type="submit"  value="buscar">Buscar</button>
       </form>

<!--Resultado de la busqueda-->

  <h1>Resultado Busqueda: "{{query}}" </h1>
  <div class="Caja">
    <div id="h2">
      <h4 text-align="center">{{DocBusc|length}} documentos encontrados en Grupo {{ user.groups.all.0.name }}</h4>

      <table class="table table-sm">
        <thead>
          <div class="text">
            <th>Titulo</th>
          </div>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for documento in DocBusc %}
          <tr>
            <td><a href="{% url 'VerDoc' documento.id %}">{{documento.Titulo}}</a></td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vacía `action` de formulario no envía solicitud al misma pagina. Utiliza

```
<form action="{{ request.path }}" method="GET">
```

Comment: De hecho no es necesario hacerlo, sino se proporciona el atributo `action`, los datos se enviarán a la URL de la página que contiene el formulario, es decir la página actual. Échale un vistaso a la [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#The_action_attribute). Es lo mismo que un `action` vació.

Comment: `action="{{ request.path }}` lo pobré pero no funciona.

Comment: En teoría si no se proporciona el atributo `action` o se deja vacío los datos deberían viajar a la pagina del formulario, pero eso es precisamente lo que no está ocurriendo. :((

Comment: @DavidCastro según veo tu vista `DocsBuscar2` no renderisa el template `solucion.html`, renderisa el template `resultados2.html`, es por eso que no se hace la petición a esa vista...

Comment: Es cierto que el render de la vista está apuntando a otro html (`resultados2.html`) pero es que ni siquiera está entrando a la función `DocsBuscar2` de mi vista  (lo sé por lo prints que coloco). Eso es lo que más me causa curiosidad, al quitar el atributo `action` la función `DocsBuscar2` de mi vista no se ejecuta.

Comment: @DavidCastro Como quieres que entre a dicha función o vista si ni siquiera haces una petición a la URL que apunta a ella?...